# Why Can't I set moment locale in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

I'm running a node-app, this is all I have in app.js:

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment().locale('fr');
console.log(moment.locale())
```

I expect this to output 'fr' but it outputs 'en' instead, when I

```
runjs app.js
```

There is a fr-folder in node_modules/moment/locale.

Here are my packages:

```
{
  "name": "zenqa",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Faq for Zenconomy.se",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "concat-files": "^0.1.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "marked": "^0.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "mustache-express": "^1.2.2",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.7",
    "php-unserialize": "0.0.1",
    "requestify": "^0.1.17",
    "validator": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Kristoffer Nolgren",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:kristoffernolgren/ZenqaMiddleware.git"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use:**

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/es";
```

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation there is a bug that prevents moment.locale from being loaded. So you can use the following code.

```
var moment = require('moment');
require('moment/locale/fr');
console.log(moment.locale());
```

Answer (score 8):

Spent hours on this just to realise I had to import the locale from `/dist` dir instead. Maybe it's just caused by my setup but might help someone

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/dist/locale/fr';

moment.locale('fr');
```

Test

```js
import fr1 from 'moment/dist/locale/fr';
import fr2 from 'moment/locale/fr';

console.log(fr1); // Locale {_calendar: {…}, ... }
console.log(fr2); // {}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the current [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/) it is possible:

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment.locale('fr');
console.log(moment().format());
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For node you can use:

```js
moment.updateLocale('es');
```

I have tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Current document is not correct. In Node.JS you still use this code:

moment.lang('fr');